# Terraform not deleting rds autoscaled aurora instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a rds aurora global database with autoscaling enabled based on CPU threshold but when I try to destroy the autoscaled instances that are not deleted by terraform is this a bug? Is there a workaround or am I missing something?

I used this module https://github.com/umotif-public/terraform-aws-rds-aurora/blob/master/main.tf

line 391 create auto-scaling of aurora rds

But the autoscaled instance state is not maintained by terraform and deleting the autoscale resource didn't work

Error message: Error: error deleting RDS Cluster InvalidDBClusterStateFault: Cluster cannot be deleted, it still contains DB instances in non-deleting state. status code: 400, request id: b62f33ee-57d8-4887-9cad-3cbf6229b4ac

Error: Error deleting DB parameter group: InvalidDBParameterGroupState: One or more database instances are still members of this parameter group my-parameter-group, so the group cannot be deleted status code: 400, request id: 8a501e66-39e5-4365-ba33-7667894b9cf6

Comment: do you have delete protection for the db instance ? if so those need to be disabled and applied through terraform

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have done this is by manually deleting it before executing the command from terraform, but it does not make sense

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).